# Query_post 5 post first / last of post_id

Tags: wp-query, query-posts

i have list post id: 1 to 100

How to:

In `post_id=50` show list `post_id=51,52,53,54,55` and `list post_id=45,46,47,48,49` by category of `post_id=50`

Any idea for help me! Thanks

Comment: How we can provide any help without seeing your code?

Comment: i can't have code. if in post_id=50; how to get list post_id=51,52,53,54,55 by category of post_id=50. Any your idea?

Comment: You have a list of post id (1 to 100). But where that list comes from? Is this list contains ID of wordpress's post? Have you displayed this list in any webpage? If yes, then have you used any plugin to show this list or your own code or anything else? And also what you have tried to achieve this till now?

Comment: post_id is list post by category. as: category_id=10 have 100 post. if you visit any post show first/last 5 post of current post_id

Answer (score 0):

Here I've written a function for you. It will return you an array of posts. You need to use is as `wpse_243452_get_posts_by_ids( 50, 5, false )` if you need to get next `X` posts then just pass the second parameter as the integer number how many posts you need and then pass `true`. If you ned the previous `X` then change the last parameter to `false`. Here `X` is equal to `$num`.

Here is your function-

```
function wpse_243452_get_posts_by_ids( $post_id, $num, $next = true ) {
    $ids = [];
    if ( $next ) {
        for ( $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ ) {
            $ids[] = $post_id;
            $post_id++;
        }
    } else {
        for ( $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ ) {
            $ids[] = $post_id;
            $post_id--;
        }
    }
    $args = [
        'post__in' => $ids
    ];
    $ids = array_filter($ids, function ($x) use ($num) { return $x < $num; });
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    return $posts;
}
```

After getting the posts you can run a `foreach` loop and decorate your posts.